# Set the path of the upload file

Tags: javascript

I'm new to js, and I have code like this, which will set the path of upload file:

```
document.getElementById("binaryFilePath").value = "location"
```

when I run this I get :

```
[Error] InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
    global code (AppAdmin, line 1)
```

Whats happening?

Comment: This will (on its own) in no way "upload a file" - please paste more code or a link to a jsfiddle

Comment: @splig: Sorry to set the path of upload file

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this

```
  function myFunction()
  {
  var x = document.getElementById("myFile").type;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
```

use fiddle url:http://jsfiddle.net/huboxpc8/